# LINQ - Remove elements based on value

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Here is what my XML file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--QTabs Data Storage-->
<SyncTimes>
  <LastSyncTime>
    <id>1</id>
    <SyncTime>3/31/2015 2:03:28 PM</SyncTime>
  </LastSyncTime>
  <LastSyncTime>
    <id>2</id>
    <SyncTime>3/31/2015 2:14:24 PM</SyncTime>
  </LastSyncTime>
  <LastSyncTime>
    <id>3</id>
    <SyncTime>3/31/2015 2:14:25 PM</SyncTime>
  </LastSyncTime>
</SyncTimes>
```

I'm trying to create a method that will remove old sync times. This is my attempt:

```
    public void deleteArchivedSyncs(int months)
    {
        var xElement = (from element in XMLDocObject.Elements("SyncTimes").Elements("LastSyncTime")
                        where Convert.ToDateTime(element.Attribute("SyncTime").Value) < DateTime.Now.AddHours(-months)
                        select element);
        xElement.Remove();
    }
```

Currently I'm running the method with a zero to see if it runs.

THis is what I'm getting:

[image]

To me it looks like here is resulting in the null exception:

```
element.Attribute("SyncTime").Value
```

But I don't understand based on looking at the XML why this would occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<SyncTime>` is not an attribute - it is an element.  Therefore the expression `element.Attribute("SyncTime")` returns null, and attempting to access `Value` throws a null reference exception.

Comment: I have been scratching my head when everytime I have to decide which one to use. xElement or XML Serializer. Any good book about this? Or site reference?

Comment: I don't understand how this relates to the question or my answer.  Did you mean to post this here?

Comment: It doesn't relate to the answer actually. It is just a quick question. Cause every time I bump into a question about XML, quite often, the answer is use xElement. The other will answer, use XML serializer. And the debate goes on. I even asked a question about serializing on XML and the same response is what I am getting. some commenting about xElement. Some answers with XML serialize.

Comment: `XElement` and `XmlSerializer` solve two different problems.  `XElement` is part of LINQ to XML, which is intended as an alternative to the traditional DOM model (using `XmlDocument` and `XmlElement`).  Both LINQ to XML and the DOM model are simply ways to build, read, and interact with XML documents.  XML serialization, on the other hand, is a way to convert an object into a portable XML representation.  `XmlSerializer` is the typical way to do this.

Comment: Make sense. Cause in my question I only want to read the XML file and reference to it. Which is the XML serializer can write as well if I understand your comment correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With XmlSerializer you can deserialize the xml to a type

```
public class LastSyncTime
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string SyncTime { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime Time  // This is used to convert DateTime to a string
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime result;
            DateTime.TryParse( SyncTime, out result );
            return result;
        }
        set
        {
            SyncTime = value.ToString();
        }
    }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute( AnonymousType = true )]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute( Namespace = "", IsNullable = false )]
public class SyncTimes
{
    private LastSyncTime[] items;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute( "LastSyncTime", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified )]
    public LastSyncTime[] Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }
        set
        {
            items = value;
        }
    }


    public static SyncTimes OpenXml( string path )
    {
        SyncTimes syncTimes;
        using ( FileStream stream = File.OpenRead( path ) )
        {
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer( typeof( SyncTimes ) );
            syncTimes = (SyncTimes)x.Deserialize( stream );
        }

        return syncTimes;
    }

    public void ToXmlFile( string path )
    {
        using ( FileStream stream = File.Create( path ) )
        {
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer( typeof( SyncTimes ) );
            x.Serialize( stream, this );
        }
    }
}
```

Your code can then use the xml file like so:

```
SyncTimes times = SyncTimes.OpenXml("data.xml");
var archived = times.Where(x => x.Time < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-months));
```